# check if null and do something

Tags: kotlin, null-check

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to figure out how to do something if a variable is null. This is what I'm trying to do

```
private var loggedInUser: User? = null

fun createActivity(activity: Activity) {
    loggedInUser?.activities?.put(activity.id, activity)
    //set loggedInUser.activities = hashMapOf() if null
}
```

Here's the User class

```
data class User(
        val firstname: String = "",
        val lastname: String = "",
        val email: String = "",
        val password: String = "",
        val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        val activities: MutableMap<String, Activity> = hashMapOf())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your definition of the `User` class, if a value for the `activities` parameter isn't provided, it will use the default. Since [`hashMapOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/hash-map-of.html) will never return null, you don't have to worry about that. In addition, `activities` is a `val` and not a nullable type, so if you have a non-null `User`, you have a non-null `activities`.

If you're looking to set some value if a result is null, check out the [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator):

```
data class User(val name: String, val friend: User? = null)
fun main() {
    val x: User? = User("X")
    val y: User? = User("Y", x)
    val friendOfFriend = y?.friend?.friend?.name ?: "No friend"
    println(friendOfFriend) // Outputs "No friend" because x.friend was null
}
```

If any value is `null` along that call chain, it uses the value provided after the `?:`, otherwise it returns the value given on the left hand side.

Of course, that's just the most idiomatic way. You could also do:

```
if (activities == null) {
    // something
}
```

Or any other traditional null checks.